# SDL Tridion GetListKeywords using Anquilla Framework

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm writing a GUI extension and using the Anquilla framework to get a list of `Keywords` within a `Category`.  I'm obtaining an XML document for the list of keywords then working with that document within my extension.

My problem is that the returned XML doesn't contain the Keyword's '`Description`' value.   I have the Title and Key etc.

My original code looks like this:

```
var category = $models.getItem("CATEGORYTCMID:);
var list = category.getListKeywords();
list.getXml();
```

A typical node returned is this:

```
<tcm:Item ID="tcm:4-1749-1024" 
Type="1024" Title="rate_one" Lock="0" IsRoot="true" 
Modified="2012-12-17T23:01:59" FromPub="010 Schema" 
Key="rate_one_value" IsAbstract="false" 
CategoryTitle="TagSelector" 
CategoryID="tcm:4-469-512" Icon="T1024L0P0" 
Allow="268560384" Deny="96" IsNew="false" 
Managed="1024"/></tcm:ListKeywords>
```

So I've tried using a Filter to give me additional column information:

```
var filter = new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter();
filter.columns = Tridion.Constants.ColumnFilter.EXTENDED;
var list = category.getListKeywords(filter);
```

Unfortunately this only gives the additional XML attributes:

```
IsShared="true" IsLocalized="false"
```

I'd really like the description value to be part of this XML without having to create a Keyword object from the XML.  Is such a thing possible?

*cough* any ideas? *cough*

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you'll have to load the Keyword itself to get the Description. 
It's not used in any lists, so it's not returned in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

You could always create a [List Extender](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_E4EFBE6E5CA24C01B2531FB15AE95AE2) to add this information to the list, but try to be smart about it since this extender will execute everytime a GetList is called.

Won't save you from having to open every keyword in the list, but you'll be doing it server-side (with Core Service/NetTcp for instance) which will probably be easier and faster than opening each keyword with Anguilla.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance I only need the one keyword, so I simply get it from the CMS.  Getting an object in Anguilla is a bit weird, here's the code:

1. In your main code area:

   ```
      var selectedKy = $models.getItem("TcmUriOfKeywordHere");
      if (selectedKy.isLoaded()) {
        p.selectedKy = selectedKy;
        this.onselectedKyLoaded();
      } else {
        $evt.addEventHandler(selectedKy, "load", this.onselectedKyLoaded);
        selectedKy.load();
      }
   ```

   It's worth noting how I store the keyword in the properties of the item, so I can obtain it in the `onselectedKyLoaded` function
2. The function called once the item is loaded

   ```
    ContentBloom.ExampleGuiExtension.prototype.onselectedKyLoaded = function (event) {
        var p = this.properties;
        var selectedDescription = p.selectedKy.getDescription();
        // do what you need to do with the description :)
    };
   ```

I resolved this, thanks to the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12805939/1221032 - Cheers Nuno :)